# How can I send a text message to multiple singular contacts in my Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sms, imessage

Periodically, I like to send friendly text messages to large groups of people in my contacts. Sending the same message to lots of people is tedious, but I've never been fully satisfied with solutions offered by existing apps. So, I started developing my own.

I started with a Shortcut that works pretty well and has a few defining characteristics:

- Messages can have "tags", such as for swapping in a contact's name, for a more personal touch.
- Contacts receive their own personal text message. **They are not part of a group message**. No publicized phone numbers or delete-me-from-the-group bombs.
- I can leave the process alone while it works; **I don't have to confirm each message to send**.
- The whole process is serialized and persisted. If the process halts due to a faulty contact (like a disconnected phone number), I can resume the process right where I left off. No contact gets sent a duplicate message.

Shortcuts are a poor man's programming, though, and I was aching for a proper development experience. So I started learning Swift and writing an app to give me a more robust, UI friendly version of the Shortcut.

Alas, I fear I may have been eager. I haven't been able to find any documentation or examples of sending an iMessage or SMS text message to a contact without the need of some UI. `MSMessageAppViewController` is not what I want, because that sort of defeats the purpose of my automation goal here.

It seems very odd to me that Shortcuts would allow me to send text messages to a bunch of contacts without needing to confirm each message, and yet I can't do the same in a Swift program. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: As far as I know there is no other way of doing without `MSMessageAppViewController`. But if you include more than one person in the `MSMessageAppViewController` it will be as you said part of a group message. Maybe there is another way of doing, would love know :]

Comment: If Apple allowed you to send SMS through an app Facebook would have already done it. I wouldn't expect Apple to allow this.

Comment: There is no way for an app to send a text message without user intervention.  This is a privacy/security thing.  Apple assumes that you wrote the shortcut (or at least imported it knowing what it does) so that is a different situation.

Comment: @Paulw11 Am I the only one that finds that odd? How are Shortcuts different than apps? Or rather what makes Shortcuts special enough that they have more liberties than apps? Is it possible to invoke/drive a Shortcut from an app?

Comment: @Craxal shortcuts can be trusted for two reasons. 1. That is an app from Apple (native Apple app) 2. The owner of the phone decides how to use the shortcuts. In our case with application, we perfectly know that there are so many apps out there that try to deceive the users, to prevent such situation Apple are pretty strict about this all.

Comment: You can look at the "source code" or steps of a shortcut. You can see exactly what it does. You can't look at the code of an app from the store. It could be silently sending text messages and you would not know, so Apple doesn't make that possible.

Comment: So it sounds like I'm stuck with the Shortcut then. However, Shortcuts can access apps, so in theory, could write an "assistant" app that handles most of the workload, and the Shortcut merely sends the actual messages? That would be a plus, because managing everything before sending the message is the biggest pain.

Answer (score -1):

This isn’t really an answer to your issue (I believe you can only use MSMessageViewController to send messages), but I did discover you can disable *iMessage* and *Group Messaging* and make it so when you send a message to a large group of people it sends them as individual, direct SMS messages.
I used this to send a text out to a  group of 90 people without inciting a mass group thread. It was annoying to setup (and if you don’t set it up properly you’ll end up making a giant group thread which is scary) and you have to remember to undo the changes after, but it worked like a charm!

See this q/a:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5211685?answerId=22908620022#22908620022